# Use jQuery text() and replace + keep line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use

```
$("#test").html($("#test").text().replace(/([a-zA-Z]+[.,]? ){50}/, 
  function(x) { return x + "... <p>new content</p> ... "; }));
```

to add some content after 50 words. How is it possible in this case to keep the original line breaks of the full content?

**I tried this**

*Alternative to jQuery text() function*
https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-text-function/

but with no success.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3wkxzpo0/

```js
$("#test").html($("#test").text().replace(/([a-zA-Z]+[.,]? ){50}/, function(x) { return x + "... <p style=\"background:red\">new content</p> ... "; }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
Hallo, <br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et  duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <a href="/example.php">test</a> takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur <img src="sdfsdf">sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
<br /><br />
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
<br /><br />
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,  vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: You mean keeping line breaks within that 50 characters?

Comment: No in the complete text.

Comment: he is using .text() so the BRs disappear. You need to loop over the html's nodes

Comment: Can line breaks occur within the first 50 characters?

Comment: @mplungjan I see that.. Guess he needs to use `.html` in place of `.text`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vanilla JS solution that iterates over the childNodes of the element, keeping track of the word count in each *textNode* and inserting the desired element when it reaches a certain word count.

```
var test = document.getElementById('test'), childNodes = test.childNodes,
    wordCount = 0, newHTML = [], maxWords = 50, toInsert = '&nbsp;<b>[50]</b>&nbsp;',
  i = 0, node = null, words = null, inserted = false;

for(i=0; i<childNodes.length; i++) {
  node = childNodes[i];
  if(node.nodeType !== 3) { // not a text node, append
    newHTML.push(node.outerHTML);
  }
  else { // is a text node, append till maxWords
    if(inserted) {
      newHTML.push(node.textContent);
    }
    else {
      words = node.textContent.replace(/^\s+/g, '').replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(/[\s\t\n+]/g);
      words = words.filter(function(_x) {
        return _x !== '';
      });
      if(wordCount + words.length < maxWords) {
        newHTML.push(node.textContent);
      }
      else {
        newHTML.push(words.slice(0, maxWords - wordCount).join(' '));
        newHTML.push(toInsert);
        newHTML.push(words.slice(maxWords - wordCount).join(' '));
        inserted = true;
      }
      wordCount += words.length;
    }
  }
}
test.innerHTML = newHTML.join('');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5t6kq02g/1/

Comment: It works but there is one issue. As you can see in your fiddle, your code remove the space after a html tag. Take a look at testtakimata. is it possible for you to fix this?

Comment: That would mean storing the starting and trailing sequence of spaces around each element as you iterate and use those exact sequences when joining back. Possible, but could get pretty complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$("#test").html($("#test").html().replace(/([a-zA-Z]+[.,]? ){50}/, function(x) { return x + "... <p style=\"background:red\">new content</p> ... "; }));
```

Comment: I tried but with .html the "insert after 50 words" is not working anymore.

Comment: @labu77 Can you please make a fiddle and share the link to check the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This works. . .just change `$("#test").text()` to `$("#test").html()`

https://jsfiddle.net/vq8yf9u9/2/

```js
$("#test").html($("#test").html().replace(/([a-zA-Z=\/<>".]+[.,]? +){50}/, function(x) { return x + "... <p style=\"background:red\">new content</p> ... "; }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
Hallo, <br /><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et  duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <a href="/example.php">test</a> takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur <img src="sdfsdf">sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
<br /><br />
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
<br /><br />
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,  vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, this works not.  the "insert after 50 words" is not working anymore

Comment: oh sorry, that was because of the regular expression, once we added all the html tags as part of input string, the regexp had to be updated to handle html tags. its working now. you can click on Run code snippet and see. . .